# Can I use 24GB SSD of utrabook s56c for Ubuntu like Windows 8?

Tags: 14.04, 15.04

My laptop has a 24GB ssd for caching Windows but I deleted Windows to use Ubuntu.
Can I use it with Ubuntu for starting more quickly and improving performance?

Comment: Yes, you can install Ubuntu on SSD if this SSD can be directly accessed by OS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. In fact I'm writing this on an Asus S56C now running Ubuntu 15.04. I've upgraded the SSD to 120GB and it runs really well. As the 24GB is quite small I would suggest putting the /home or /usr directory on the second HDD. You will need to disable secure boot and manually setup the partitions to handle the UEFI. There is a good write up here.

http://www.tecmint.com/ubuntu-15-04-installation-on-uefi-firmware/